# Merge "signal" and "reception"

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

The tags [signal](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signal) and [reception](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reception) would seem to be synonyms of each other.

Can they please be merged and one be made a synonym of the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I merged these and made [signal](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signal) the master, since it appears to be the more popular of the two.